# Automated feh image show via python on a raspberry pi with sensor inputs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

**Summary:**
How to send commands or keypresses to a running feh process via python? To pause, goto next picutre ...

Hello community,

i am rediscovering the advantages of the raspberry pi and right now i try to use it to display all pictures in a given folder as a slide show on a TV. It works well with "feh" just like this:

`feh -Y -x -D 5 -B black -F -Z --on-last-slide quit -r /home/pi/Pictures`

My second step was to start that via Python, which worked well like this:

`subprocess.call(["feh", "-Y", "--r /home/pi/Picture"])`

When it's running, it takes keyboard inputs like

h for pause; arrow right for next picture; arrow left for prev picture

In my final solution, there will be no keyboard attached, but some custom buttons connected to the GPIO pins which should control these 3 functions (pause/continue, next picture, prv picture). So i tried to call the commands for that via pipe to the running feh subprocess:

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(args=["feh","--r /home/pi/Pictures", "-Y", "-B black", "-F", "-D 5", "-Z", "-x"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.communicate(input=0x0071)
p1.communicate(b"h")
```

But that does not work.

I tried some variatons, too: The shell=true parameter to the subprocess call, installing a library named "keyboard" (`sudo pip3 install keyboard` and then `keyboard.send("h")` and then ran the python script as root cause "keyboard" required root access) and a few other things in that direction, but none of them had any effect on the running feh slide show.

My workaround goes like this and works, more or less:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(args=["feh","/home/pi/Pictures/picture1.jpeg", "-Y", "-B black", "-F", "-Z", "-x"])
time.sleep(5)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(args=["feh","/home/pi/Pictures/picture2.jpeg", "-Y", "-B black", "-F", "-Z", "-x"])
time.sleep(1)
p1.terminate()
<<GPIO logic and timers and stuff here>>
p2.terminate()
```

But it's not very elegant, i have to create my own slideshow-logic (pick each picture by my own code instead of just passing the folder to feh) so i'm hoping someone can give me a hint on how to solve this with the communicate variant or maybe a complete different approach? I'm happy for all the ideas you might have!

Comment: I used `feh` a couple of different ways... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854622/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53947552/2836621

Comment: Hi Mark, on my research i've seen these threads and they helped me a lot with that workaround method (start and kill severals subprocesses) but i would prefer to use the feh slideshow function if that is possible

Comment: Surely if you only have three buttons, FWD, BACK, PAUSE, you can just use three signals USR1,USR2,STOP ?

Comment: yes just these three. i will try to learn how to use USR. thanks already, i'll let you know if i managed to use that

Comment: You send them with `os.kill()`

Comment: Thanks. I read this: https://masterccc.github.io/memo/process_com/  and i can figure how the stop thing works (pausing the process) but how could i link the usersignals to the functions i want?

Comment: Hi Mark, the USR1 and 2 were already linked to back and forward automatically. So this worked. The Stop gave me some strange behaviour so i use a loop for the slideshow effect in my python now and build the logic for stop/continue there.